# If a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is proper, then it tends to infinity as $x\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

I came across this problem the other day, I've played around with it but still don't really have any ideas:

"A function, $f$, is said to be proper if the pre-image of any compact set is compact. Show that if $f$ is proper then $\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty}|f(x)| = \infty$"

Comment: when you say $\infty$ presumably this is $ \pm \infty $?

Comment: if not, the image will always be contained in a compact set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the theorem is not true. Then, there is a positive number M, such that |f(x)|<= M for arbitrarily large M, i.e. f(x) is in [-M , M] for arbitrarily large x.Hence, the pre-image of the compact set [-M,M] is unbounded, hence not compact, a contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

Let $r>0$ and let $C$ denote the preimage of compact set $\left[-r,r\right]$.
Then $C$ is compact hence bounded, so: $C\subset\left[-s,s\right]$
for some $s\in(0,\infty)$ large enough. Then we have $\left|x\right|>s\Rightarrow\left|f\left(x\right)\right|>r$.

For any $r>0$ such an $s>0$ can be found and we are allowed to conclude
that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|=\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left|f\left(x\right)\right|=\infty$.

Comment: Infact, the theorem is true for maps, for which pre-image of bounded sets are bounded.

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee Yes you are right. I didn't even realize until you attended me.